# How can I compile, run AML with ACPI, or how should I utilize ACPI functions?

Tags: operating-system, acpi

I'm trying to write a kernel and plan to use ACPI on some issues (e.g. identify interrupt source on APIC).

However, I'm really a beginner on this, I read the related documentation and still do not have any clue on how to configure and use ACPI functions.

I have some basic understanding that:

1, there are some ACPI tables will be mapped in memory space, within which DSDT and SSDT will provide some definition blocks.

2, The definition block are AML code

3, I can retrieve some information directly from ACPI tables (e.g. I/O APIC base address)

4, Further information some times need to run ACPI objects.

These are basically my understanding about ACPI. However, how should I use AML code, how should I run ACPI objects. I do not have a clue.

So if any one can provide a basic structure of how this mechanism works, how some basic functions provided by ACPI can be realized by OS??

Thanks a lot! I'll keep reading the documentation and try to find some thing that can help me on understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with linux, try the following (as root), it will give you a good start (you should install the distro relevant package, like acpica-tools):

```
$acpidump > dump.bin

$acpixtract -x dump.bin
```

(this will create a binary file for each table in the initial dump file. lots of ".dat" file)

```
$iasl -d *dat
```

(this will disassemble the binary files to human readable format)

you can also download intel's implementation for the iasl compiler from github (look it up. it is very easy to compile)

Answer (score 3):

My advice is:

a) If you're a beginner, implement support for "PIC chips" while taking into account future support for things like IO APIC and MSI but not implementing that support yet (e.g. just dummy stubs, etc); and then worry about adding support for IO APICs (and MSI) and ACPI later (e.g. after most of your OS has been done, including device drivers, file systems, etc). Note that this is a big part of why I advocate a "kernel tells device driver which resources it should use" approach (rather than a "device driver tells the kernel which resources it wants" approach) - so you can add support for IO APIC and MSI later without touching any of the code for any of the device drivers.

b) For ACPI's AML; it's a nasty festering mess. Specifically, the OS has to tell AML what the OS is (e.g. using an `\_OS` object in AML to tell AML the operating system's name), if the OS isn't recognized by the computer's AML then the AML will typically fall back to a crippled "bare minimum functionality" mode, and the AML for lots of computers will only recognize (various versions of) Windows. The result is that to use the full functionality provided by AML your OS has to pretend that it is (a version of) Windows, and has to have the same behaviour as that version of Windows, which is not well documented (e.g. not included in the ACPI specs at all) and not easily discovered by "trial and error" techniques. If that's not bad enough; various computers have buggy AML, and you need "who knows how many" workarounds for these bugs. The most practical way to work around this problem is by relying on a well-tested code written by other people. More specifically; you will probably want to port ACPICA (see https://acpica.org/ ), which is an open-source and OS-independent implementation of ACPI that includes an AML interpreter and hides/abstracts a lot of the pain.

Comment: Use of ACPICA doesn't abolish the necessity of having quirks against badly prepared tables in the firmwares.